# Declaring a Generic class

Tags: java, generics

When declaring a Generic class, does this

```
public class MyClass <Integer, Character, String> extends SuperClass <T> implements SomeInterface <V>, SomeOtherInterface <W> {...}
```

make T an Integer, V a Character, and W a String? Or in the Driver/MainMethod would I need to declare each variable independently? For ex.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    SuperClass<Integer> one = new SuperClass<>(100);
    ...
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: _" does this make T an Integer, V a Character, and W a String?"_ No, do this: `public class MyClass <Integer, Character, String> extends SuperClass <Integer> implements SomeInterface <Character>, SomeOtherInterface <String> {...}`

Comment: I don't think `<Integer, Character, String>` after a class name is what he wants. `String` is no longer `java.lang.String` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not sure I understand your question correctly, but if you're wanting `T` to be `Integer`, `V` a `Character`, and `W` a `String`, you need to declare your Generic like so:

```
public class MyClass <T extends Integer, V extends Character, W extents String> extends SuperClass <T> implements SomeInterface <V>, SomeOtherInterface <W> {...}
```

But I don't see why you would want to use the generics on `MyClass` in this case. You could do this and it will essentially be the same thing:

```
public class MyClass extends SuperClass <Integer> implements SomeInterface <Character>, SomeOtherInterface <String> {...}
```